# CSS not Applied on Drupal 7 Webform email template

Tags: drupal, webforms, drupal-7

I am using Webform Module of Drupal While Editing tpl.php file of mail the CSS i Write is not Applied to ma Actual Mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use inline CSS for styling HTML emails. It is a bit different that styling HTML that will be shown standard way, in web browser. Check on some tutorial on this subject, i.e.

https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: Thanks @MilanG this helps me